# Why is this piece-wise limit equal to 2?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2x-2,  & x < 3 \\
2x-4, & x \ge 3
\end{cases}
$$
Why is

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h} = 2  ??$$

Note the (+) in the limit.

If $h \to 0$ from the positive side, then we have something like:

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(3.0001)-f(3)}{0} = 2  ??$$
$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{2-2}{0} = \frac{0}{0} = 2  ??$$

How do you get from indeterminate $\frac{0}{0}$ to 2 ?

UPDATE: 
I did it like this:  $$\lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{[2(3+h)-4]-2}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{6+2h-4-2}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{2h}{h} = 2 $$

Comment: Also note that $f(3.0001)$ is not equal to $2$ so your assertion $2-2=0$ in the numerator is not correct....

Comment: I think you missed the point of why I wrote f(3.0001).    As h->0, the numerator is basically approaching f(3) - f(3), which is 0.    The closer h gets to 0, yet stays positive, the closer the numerator gets to f(3) - f(3), because f(3+h) will map to the 2nd piece (2x-4)... which turns into 2-2....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{[2(x+h)-4]-(2x-4)}{h}=\frac{2h}{h}=2$$

Holds for all $x$ and so the fact that the limit is $2$ shouldn't be surprising. You can't just plug in $0$ to the denominator and expect something good to happen. In your example you should have

$$\frac{f(3.0001)-f(3)}{0.0001} = 2$$ which is indeed true if you plug into your function.

Comment: It's f(3), not f(x).....So, I don't understand why you didn't evaluate f(3) in the numerator, and instead used (2x-4).  Shouldn't it be:  $$\frac{[2(x+h)-4]-3}{h}$$

Comment: @JackOfAll I was using a slightly more general form that shows that the limit is $2$ for all $x>3$. *both* $x$'s should be $3$ to limit it this instance.

Comment: @JackOfAll does this make sense? Do you have a further question about my answer?

Comment: I did it like this:  $$\lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{[2(3+h)-4]-2}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{6+2h-4-2}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{2h}{h} = 2 $$